# How to resolve Hyperledger Fabric GRPC error on AWS EC2 instances?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

It seems as though grpc is using some fairly random ports from my CLI client which I haven't manually opened.

Has anyone else had troubles with Fabric on AWS EC2 in regards to security groups and the firewalled ports? How would one create a relatively safe security group that's open enough to allow for these random grpc ports? Is there a specific port range this CLI client uses?

```
2018-04-06 13:33:19.399 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 3a3 transport: http2Server.HandleStreams failed to read frame: read tcp X.X.X.X:7050->X.X.X.X:51502: read: connection reset by peer

2018-04-06 13:33:32.481 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 3d5 transport: http2Server.HandleStreams failed to read frame: read tcp X.X.X.X:7050->X.X.X.X:51518: read: connection reset by peer

2018-04-06 13:33:44.610 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 41f transport: http2Server.HandleStreams failed to read frame: read tcp X.X.X.X:7050->X.X.X.X:51522: read: connection reset by peer
```

Ports **51502**, **51518**, **51522** referenced above from the `orderer` logs.

These errors stemmed from a CLI client issuing a `./peer chaincode instantiate` command which is failing.

Comment: Ports 51502, 51518, 51522  are just ephemeral ports used by the CLI (standard TCP stuff).  Can you set CORE_LOGGING_GRPC=debug for the CLI and post the results?

Comment: @gari-singh do you mind if I email you at your gmail? The log files are fairly large with debug mode on. I'm also on the hyperledger fabric chat.

Comment: sure ... you can also try posting your logs to https://pastebin.com/ and then including a link here as well

Comment: Did this ever get solved? we are seeing a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got the same error until I opened all ports for outbound connections on my peers.
Try to fix rules for your peer:

[image: Please try to fix rules for your peer]